# Android widget providers & main application question

Tags: android, android-widget

Alright, i seem to be asking a lot today but i'm pretty much stumped at this part after reading the documentation. Or maybe i'm just doing it wrong.

I'm doing an app where the user is able to create a widget from the application itself, which means :

1) I click on my app in the menu screen

2) App boots up, user fills in details

3) User hits create button

4) Data gets saved into a file, probably XML

4) Application closes, widget gets planted on the screen of the device in a 2x2 box.

However, when i read through various tutorials and documentation for android, it seems like the widget provider and application are two different entities altogether and it doesn't sound like they can be merged as one (meaning data cannot be transferred).

Am i still able to create my application using the original ideation or do i have to change the entire thing drastically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: i'm trying to create an application that creates a widget on the main screen whilst storing the data the user has filled in so that he/she can reaccess the data through the application.

Comment: i know the description's pretty vague, but all i want to know is if an android application can instantly create a widget via a push of a button or does the user need to go from the add>widgets>widgetname portion to add it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine an app with widgets in one APK. That's not a problem at all. They also can share data in various ways (shared preferences, files, SQLite, ...). The problem starts with the idea that the widget can be placed via your app. Widgets have to be placed by the user, he has to select the widget from the widget-menu and place it where he wants it. Your whole concept can still be done, and is pretty often - using a [ConfigurationActivity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring).

That is pretty much a normal activity that's invoked when the user selects the widget.
You can customize that to your likings, including some things that prompt the user to input data, select preferences and so on. After that, you can build your widget with the specifications from that activity in your widget update method. It gets placed by the user, and thats it.

Comment: thanks for your clear and concise description. that's a huge relief knowing that my application can still be done!

Answer (score 0):

The wigdet is apart of its application.

The user can enter information from a widget and you can use different methods of storing and sharing the information. 
Such as SharedPreference,SQLITE(RECOMMENDED).

You will be able to use either one of this to exchange data the user enters between your widget and main acitivty.

EDIT:

TO add a widget by a button click instead of the original way. 
You may need to look through the Android OS and find out how the widget is added from their. And maybe create a method of some sort to do this.

I dont think it is a class that allows you to do this. I believe the Android OS is only packaged with this way of longpress on the homescreen.

Comment: yeah i don't think i'll be able to edit through the layers of android's library just to meld the entire application and widget creation together. and besides, it wouldn't be approved if i submitted it to the app store.

Comment: This might not be a solution considering the sheer amount of work, stability and the "hack"-factor. But keep in mind, this is android - there is no approval process in the Android Market.

Comment: @alextsc EXACTLY! lol..But still it wouldnt be a good practice to do. Could cause other problems and confusion with the android OS itself. So as i stated in my answer. There isnt any way to accomplish this in android

Comment: mmk. i get it now. and uhh, there's no approval process in the Android Market? i didn't know o_o